# What Does this Code Snippet Do?

Tags: wp-config

I got this error message when I was installing a plugin: "Unable to locate WordPress Content directory (wp-content)".

I found a solution here: http://[wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-find-content-directory-wp-content](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-find-content-directory-wp-content)

They suggested adding the following code to the wp-config.php file:

```
if(is_admin()) {
    add_filter('filesystem_method', create_function('$a', 'return "direct";' ));
    define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0751 );
}
```

This solution worked for me. My questions are:

a) What does this code do?

b) If I run into the same error on the production server is it safe to use this code?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part (`add_filter()`) tells WordPress to use the direct-write method. The second part (`define()`) tells WordPress to apply `0751` permissions to any directory it creates. [More information here](http://www.viper007bond.com/2009/05/07/wordpress-how-to-force-direct-filewrites-for-upgrades/).

I would **not consider using the Direct Write method to be safe** to use in a live, public, shared-hosting environment.

Also, it might not - and in fact probably won't - work in a shared-hosting environment.

Comment: Hi Chip, Thank you for the help. I guess I'll use it on my local machine (Mac running WP 3.1.2) and not use it on the production server.

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is a bad idea.Though the permission itself might not be an issue the method is.

751 is a file system permissions (chmod), it means:

User: read/write/execute
Group: read/execute
All: execute